# using logarithms to solve the following equation to find x

Tags: logarithms

$9^{2x} = 27^{1-x}$ ?? I'm really struggling with this questions. I appreciate your help and if you can please show me your working out so I can understand it too,

Comment: $9=3^2$ and $27=3^3$

Comment: Observe that $27= 9^2$.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano $9^2=81$ :)

Comment: @JackYoon Ehm... ...ehm... ...oops... ...mmh... :(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it is this
$$9^{2x} = 27^{1-x}$$
then you can use
$$
9 = 3^2\,\,\text{and}\,\,27=3^3
$$
to get
$$
\left(3^2\right)^{2x} = \left(3^3\right)^{1-x}\\
3^{4x}=3^{3(1-x)}
$$
you can solve without logs. i.e.
$$
3^a = 3^b\,\,\text{iff}\,\,a=b
$$

Answer (score 3):

As $m\log(a)=\log(a^m),$ where both logarithm remain defined.

Taking logarithm in both sides, $$2x\cdot\log(9)=(1-x)\log(27)$$

Now $\log(27)=\log(3^3)=3\log3$ and $\log(9)=\log(3^2)=2\log3$

and $\log3\ne0$ can be cancelled safely from both sides

Comment: +1 for actually answering the OP question (using logs) :)

Answer (score 0):

Noting that $9^{2x}=(3^2)^{2x}=3^{4x}$ and $27^{1-x}=(3^3)^{1-x}=3^{3(1-x)}$ we get $$3^{4x}=3^{3(1-x)}$$ and by taking the logarithm in base $3$ we have $4x=3(1-x)$ whose unique solution is $x=\frac{3}{7}$

Comment: hey thank you alot! it makes so much sense now xD

Comment: @joly you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

$log_3\left( 9^{2x} \right) = log_3\left( 27^{1-x} \right)$

${2x} \cdot log_3\left( 9 \right) = ({1-x}) \cdot log_3\left( 27 \right)$

${2x} \cdot log_3\left( 3^2 \right) = ({1-x}) \cdot log_3\left( 3^3 \right)$

${2x} \cdot 2 = ({1-x}) \cdot 3$

${4x} = 3 - {3x}$

${7x} = 3$

$x = \frac{3}{7}$